# Comparison Operators - Greater than or Equal to - Not Working

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

Just started using JQuery recently. (Fairly recently, I suppose...)
What am I doing wrong here?

```
var userDate = new Date();
if(userDate.getHours() => 12)
{
    var post = $('p[title="test"]');
    post.text('Would you look at the time?');
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing with the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition is flipped.

```
   var userDate = new Date();
    if(userDate.getHours() >= 12)
    {
        var post = $('p[title="test"]');
        post.text('Would you look at the time?');
    }
```

Comment: Well, this is a little fishy.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to use `>=` instead of `=>`, wrong sequence of greater or equal operator. The equal to = comes after > then in `>=` comparison operator. You can read more about comparion operators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

```
var userDate = new Date();
if(userDate.getHours() >= 12)
{
    var post = $('p[title="test"]');
    post.text('Would you look at the time?');
}
```

> Greater than or equal `>=` Returns true if the left operand is greater
>   than or equal to the right operand, [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(userDate.getHours() => 12) {...}
```

Should be

```
 if(userDate.getHours() >= 12) {...}
```

The wrong way round maybe?

Comment: Chill out, stop rushing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I must admit sometimes I get confused with the ***less than or equal to*** or ***greater than or equal to***.

less than or equal to is

```
<=
```

greater than or equal to is

```
>=
```

But, if you can't remember these and your code isn't working it's always worth to simplify it buy doing something like this.

```
var userDate = new Date();
if(userDate.getHours() > 11){
    var post = $('p[title="test"]');
    post.text('Would you look at the time?');
}
```

This means

**Greater than eleven**

This is the same but I think it's easier to understand, it must be *12 or greater*